# DAX Measure count of customer with one specific product

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax, analytics, measure

I am trying to get a distinct count of my customer who purchase a specific product and show all the other product they purchased as well. I tried to put the product name in the filter, but that would not show the other products.

Customer Count = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(CustomerKey),'Customers Products'[ProductName]'='Thigh Master').
when I show it in a table it show it like this:

`Customer Name           Product Name

John Doe                Thigh Master`


but I would like to see:

`Customer Name           Product Name

John Doe                Thigh Master

John Doe                Ab Roller

John Doe                Ab Master`

Answer (score 0):

In your report, add 2 slicers (Customer, Product) and 2 Tables:

-First Table will have the count of how much the customer bought the selected product

-Second table will have all the products he bought. the trick is to disable the interaction between the second table and the Product slicer. that way the table won't be filtered by the selected product

Comment: is there any way to to write the measure as "at least product name ="Thigh Master"", if the customer has more products that would show as well?

Comment: I dont think so, why would you need this measure? I might be missing something

Comment: because I am using this measure in multiple reports in the dashboard, couple of them in drill through detail reports

Comment: In the report page, there is a specific customer selected? if so you don't need the count customer. In the table you would select customername, productname, count of the fact table). This will show you the list of products selected. To show all other products you need another table that is not interacting with the slicer. You dont need custom measures

Comment: can this issue be solved on the measure level, may be a measure that returns true() or false() if this customer bought at least a specific product without filtering out the rest of the products?